# Unit balls and the Schatten norms

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, trace

I have a very naive question:

Let $A$ and $B$ $n \times n$ (complex) matrices with operator norms $\|A\| \leq 1$ and $\|B\| \leq 1.$ Pick a $1 \leq p < \infty.$ Then with a constant $K_p$ (depending only on $p$ ) one might have that 
 $$ (\mbox{Tr } |A-B|^p)^{1/p} \leq K_p n. $$

Obviously, $K_p \leq 2$. But what (or there) is a better upper bound for $K_p?$

Comment: With $p=1$, you get, with $A=I$ and $B=-I$ that $\text{Tr}\,|A-B|=2n$, so in that case you cannot do better.

Comment: oh,thanks. so the question is trivial...

Comment: At least in the case $p=1$. For larger $p$ you get, with that example, $2n^{1/p}$ which is less than $2n$.

Comment: I mean the question is wrong:  $K_pn$ can be replaced by $K_pn^{1/p}$ and you are right...